# Tools for game animation frames generation

Tags: android, ios, animation, graphics, photoshop

For any game development, the most important thing needed is good animation to attract users. The animation consists of various frames (individual pictures played in sequence). I had been using Photoshop and Flash to generate frames for my games so far. But it's time-consuming effort to generate each individual frame and play it perfectly in sequence.

**I am wondering if there's a smart and easy to use tool for Mac or PC which I can use to generate game Characters and all animation frames with ease & speed?**

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Any good tools to create game character frames other than Photoshop? Please share.